# How can data be stored inside a class where everything is static?

Tags: swift, class, static, swift5

I have a class developed by someone that is like this

```
class CarsDatabase {
  
    private static var cars: [Car] = []
    
    static func saveCar(vehicle: Car) {
        cars.append(vehicle)
    }
```

Then I was asked to read cars from a CSV file and use the method `saveCar` from `CarsDatabase` to save it to the "database".

Reading from the CSV happens on another class called `FetchCarData`.

```
class FetchCarData {

private let fileName = "cars.csv"

func readData() {
  // I was asked to implement this and save to the database
  // Using saveCar from CarsDatabase

  // so I read all rows on the text file and I have a loop to fill
  // the database

  for row in rows {
    let newCar = Car(name:row[0], brand:row[1], price:row[2])
    // here is my problem
    // save car is static and must be called like

    CarsDatabase.saveCar(vehicle:newCar)

    // how can I store that on something that is not an instance?
  }
```

`CarsDatabase.saveCar(vehicle:newCar)` is not an instance and will disappear on the next loop interaction. How can I store that on something that is not an instance?

The tell me not to remove any `static` keywords from the several functions.

I say it is impossible.

Comment: Did you mean `CarsDatabase.saveCar(vehicle:newCar)`?

Comment: yep, typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work after that?

Comment: You said “[saveCar] is not an instance and will disappear on the next loop interaction.” ... What do you mean by that? It is appending it to to that array, no? If something is disappearing, the problem does not rest in this code.

Comment: Is this a programming example/test, or a real world problem? The idea of `static` methods and `static` properties is a really bad practice. The idea of using a singleton/shared instance is a little better, but not much.

Comment: I don’t understand what issue is, since both the property and the function is static in CarsDatabase everything works fine.

Comment: `"CarsDatabase.saveCar(vehicle:newCar) is not an instance and will disappear on the next loop interaction."` `newCar` *is* an instance, and it *won't* disappear, because it'll be kept alive by the `CarsDatabase.car` array. It's messy, but it's not totally broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this is with the [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.

```
class CarsDatabase {
    static let shared = CarsDatabase()

    private var cars: [Car] = []

    private init() {}

    func saveCar(vehicle: Car) {
        cars.append(vehicle)
    }
}
```

Use `CarsDatabase.shared` to access the instance.

Save a car like this:

```
let car = Car()
CarsDatabase.shared.saveCar(vehicle: car)
```

Comment: I cannot make saveCar not static. That is the point. They want me to implement it as it is.

Comment: @Duck When you have a shared instance, it's as if the methods and properties were static. There is only one instance that will ever exist.

Comment: @Duck You will see this pattern a lot - `UserDefaults.standard`, `UIDevice.current`, `UIScreen.main`, `UIApplication.shared`, etc.

Comment: I know. What I am saying is that I cannot make saveCar an instance method it has to remain a class method.

Comment: ok, I will remove the static and we will see.

Comment: The following compiles :   `typealias Car = Int // Just to have something`         
`class CarsDatabase {
    static let shared = CarsDatabase()
    private static var cars: [Car] = []
    static func saveCar(vehicle: Car) {
        cars.append(vehicle)
    }
}`
    and use as        `CarsDatabase.saveCar(vehicle: 10)`

Comment: @claude31 Then you are just where the OP started. The `shared` does nothing here. See their comment on their own question when aheze suggested it was a typo error, `"yep, typo. Fixed. Thanks."`. My answer is just another way of achieving it.

Comment: What difference will it make to use `shared` when everything is already static, what is the improvement?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson It's almost the same as just all `static`, but the difference is that the data is shared for anything using the `shared` instance but **not** for other custom instances. A new `CarsDatabase` instance can also be used individually, without interfering with the `shared` instance.

Comment: Are you really talking about a singleton here? Maybe you should remove that from your answer. A singleton has only one instance since only one can be created.